# Issue with rewritting URL to friendly URL when parameter has %23

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, parameters, friendly-url

I’m working on a website written in PHP, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - the website makes an API call based off URL parameters such as a username as well as some other data.

I have one main file that is used to display data, lets call it user.php - the file accepts URL parameters to display the API data based off a certain user and which "tab" they are currently viewing (tabbed page based off URL params), the "tab" being based off the last URL parameter of page="xxxx"

For example:  website.com/user.php?platform=x&username=Name&page=overview - the API data is displayed on the page based off username and platform parameters, the page parameter just indicates they are viewing a specific section of the user.php file.

The .htaccess file does some rewrites so that those parameters are rewritten to friendly URL’s like website.com/user/platform/username/pagename

The issue I’m running into is when a user’s name has a hash (#) in the name.  I’m currently replacing the hash with ‘%23’.  When I do this, there is no issue displaying the data on the “overview” section of the user.php page website.com/user/platform/user%23name/overview , but when I click a link to display another section of user.php such as website.com/user/platform/user%23name/otherpage it all breaks

If I have a username without ‘%23’ everything works fine, for example website.com/user/platform/username/overview and then click a link to website.com/user/platform/username/otherpage

Is there anything I need to be aware of with a URL parameter that includes a hash or ‘%23’ in it?  I can’t seem to figure out why it works fine with the initial page parameter but not any others.

Here's my .htaccess for the friendly URLs

`RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /user.php?platform=$2&gtag=$3&page=$4 [L]`

`RewriteRule ^/user.php?platform=$2&gtag=$3&page=$4 /user/$2/$3/$4 [L,R=301]`

Comment: I do not believe you that you second rewrite rule works ..

Comment: you must use in php url_encode() then it will work

Comment: @MaxMuster Thanks for your super quick reply!

The rewrite rule does work when a users name is "david", but not when a users name is "david#1234" which I'm converting to "david%231234"

Answer (score 0):

You say you make a api call so the data do not come from the user input.

there is a trick but is ugly:
You could use the global variables $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] or $_ENV[REQUEST_URI]
they would contain the 'nice' URL and you could explode it by "/" and get the real variables. Because of your rule you are landing on user.php and it should not break the redirect. I tested it on my server and it worked.

I tried with

```
https://www.example.com/te%23st/te%23st/te%23st/te%23st
```

and the $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] was

```
/te%23st/te%23st/te%23st/te%23st
```

so you could even rewrite your rule to:

```
RewriteRule "^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$" "/user.php" [L]
```

it would work and you do not depend on the server rewriting.

Comment: When I send the data, I'm using javascript to convert a user name such as username#123 to username%23123 prior to API submission.  This has the same result as urlencode($username).  Both convert the # to %23

Comment: Thanks Max, I tried enclosing the first rewrite rule with no luck, and then did the second as well.  Still experiencing the same issue.  

Enclosing the rewrite rules still works fine for usernames without %23, but It seems as though the page parameter (the last parameter) is being completely ignored when a username has %23 in it :(

Comment: yes the reason is that in a link the fragment or  # has a special importance in HTML. try to send your form with x-www-form-urlencoded.